# When trying to add a paragraph while using \multicols* the text goes to the bottom of the page

Tags: multicol

I have the following code:

```
\begin{multicols*}{3}
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 

more text
\columnbreak
\begin{minted}{python}
    def python(self, n):
        i = 0
        while i in range(n + 1):
            print("an example code")

\end{minted}
\end{multicols*}
```

I would want the more text to appear with a line gap between it and the other text, however, it appears at the bottom of the page instead

https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4ZGy.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Using `multicols*` means you asking it to make columns of full size. Your first column has just 2 paragraphs in the example and so the only stretchable part to fill the column is between the two paragraphs so one appears on the top and one at the bottom.

As you don't show a full example (which is much better as it can be run by others!) I can only guess, but you probably use a document class that does not produces ragged columns but flushed columns. So either change that (`\raggedbottom`), or use `multicols` without the star so that it balances your columns.